# Is there a way to enable UNICODE formatting in Dev C++

Tags: c++, unicode, dev-c++

This question has never been asked before.

I am using Dev C++ version 5.11. so, I was surfing across youtube for game libraries, and I came across olcConsoleGameEngine.h. I do not like to use Visual C++ for some particular reasons, and olcConsoleGameEngine.h requires *UNICODE* support.

This is not supported in Dev C++ by default. I burned through the dev c++ Manual but came nothing related to *UNICODE* support.

So here I ask you, how to allow *UNICODE* formatting and *UNICODE* compiling in Dev C++.

I've tried running olcConsoleGameEngine.h and I receive the following error:

```
127 2 [Error] Please enable UNICODE for your compiler! VS: Project Properties -> General -> Character Set -> Use Unicode. Thanks! - Javidx9
```

The following error says the options to enable *UNICODE* for VS, however I am not using VS, and I need a way to enable it for Dev C++.

Help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Dev C++ is the IDE but what you need to adjust is the compiler. Which compiler are you using? I guess you use g++. Hence, this is the one you have to google for. Visual Studio allows the use of different compilers as well but by default it's the MSVC, and this is what the mentioned VS project property is addressing.

Comment: FYI: [MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/)

Comment: Configure MinGW compiler for Dev C++ @S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "enable UNICODE" option is just a convenience to make sure `#define UNICODE` happens before `#include windows`. There's no magic.